# Systemd unit file for daemon not working on boot

Tags: linux, systemd, raspberry-pi, raspbian, transmission

I am trying to make the `transmission-daemon` start on boot on my Raspberry Pi model B using `systemd`. I am at a point where I can stop and start the daemon using `systemctl`, but automatic startup on boot is not working yet.

I have created the unit file `/etc/systemd/system/transmission.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Transmission daemon
Requires=network.target

[Service]
Type=forked
User=pi
ExecStart=/usr/bin/transmission-daemon -f

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I have enabled the service using:

```
sudo systemctl enable transmission.service
```

Unfortunately...no joy on reboot. However, a manual start works:

```
sudo systemctl start transmission.service
```

What am I doing wrong? I am on the latest Raspbian Jessie.

**EDIT (2015/10/16)**

According to the output of `ps aux` and `systemctl status transmission.service`, the daemon is up and running. However, I cannot reach the web interface. If I stop the running instance of the daemon and restart it manually, then I am able to reach the web interface.

On request, here are the outputs for `ps aux` and `netstat` after rebooting the Pi:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/29638164/ps_before.txt
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/29638164/netstat_before.txt

and here are the same outputs after manually restarting the daemon:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/29638164/ps_after.txt
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/29638164/netstat_after.txt

by using:

```
$ killall transmission-daemon
$ sudo systemctl start transmission.service
```

Comment: What does systemctl status say after booting? Or systemctl --failed?

Comment: Hmmm...it appears 0 units failed...odd...

Comment: So what is the status of the service? Also what is the default target? Perhaps you are not in the mukti user target?

Comment: I do not know how to check or add myself to the multi-user target :( . According to `systemctl status transmission.service` the service is `active (running)`. However, I am not able to reach the web-client via my browser. If I do a `systemctl stop` followed by a `systemctl start` I am able to reach the web-client.

Comment: Then please update your question. Add process listing and netstat output after booting and after restarting the service.

Comment: Enable the service and reload the unit files using `systemctl daemon-reload` and check.

Comment: Oh I read your comment now. Just ignore my previous comment.

Comment: @Bram I added the outputs you requested in my question.

Comment: Perhaps I should have been more explicit; please add the output of netstat -nap|grep transmission before and after.  That should tell us whether the process is listening on an external interface or not.

Answer (score 1):

`Requires=network.target` tells `systemd` that this service needs network connections activated at some point, but *does not specify this service should be started up only **after** the networking is up*.

(Yes, there are services that can deal with network interfaces appearing, getting reconfigured and/or disappearing while the service is running. For those, `Requires=network.target` would work just fine. In the modern world, with hot-plugging and IPv6 becoming more common, perhaps more services should be like that.)

From `systemd.unit(5)` man page (emphasis mine):

> Note that requirement dependencies do not
>   influence the order in which services are started or stopped. This
>   has to be configured independently with the `After=` or `Before=`
>   options. If a unit `foo.service` requires a unit `bar.service` as
>   configured with `Requires=` and no ordering is configured with `After=`
>   or `Before=`, then **both units will be started simultaneously** and
>   without any delay between them if `foo.service` is activated. Often,
>   it is a better choice to use `Wants=` instead of `Requires=` in order
>   to achieve a system that is more robust when dealing with failing
>   services.

If you want to specify that the service should start only after networking is up and all the interfaces have their IP addresses, you should do something like this instead:

```
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target
```

From `systemd.special(7)` man page:

> `network-online.target`
>
> Units that strictly require a configured network connection should
>   pull in `network-online.target` (via a `Wants=` type dependency) and
>   order themselves after it. This target unit is intended to pull in
>   a service that delays further execution until the network is
>   sufficiently set up. What precisely this requires is left to the
>   implementation of the network managing service.

Answer (score 0):

Transmission-daemon can't bind a port because the network interface hasn't got the IP address yet. Assuming the IP address is going to be 192.168.xxx.xxx the issue can be resolved by adding ExecStartPre option to transmission-daemon systemd unit with the following command

```
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/timeout 120 sh -c "until ifconfig | grep -m 1 '192\.168'; do sleep 1 ; done"
```

More details can be found [here](http://minusminuszero.blogspot.ca/2017/04/starting-transmission-daemon-on-boot-rpi.html)